# How come I cannot return data array in global context?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error.
I am simply trying to access the array data.js in my Form.js component and map over the properties. But it is saying the data is undefined when I console.log. I set my data to reviews state default. Then I passed the state variable reviews to the value props so Form.js can access it. Any help is appreciated.

context.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import data from './data';

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState(data);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    return <AppContext.Provider value={reviews}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
    return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { AppProvider } from './context';

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppProvider>
        <App />
    </AppProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import Form from './Form';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route exact path='/'>
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/form'>
                <Form />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Form.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context';
const Form = () => {
    const { reviews } = useGlobalContext();
    console.log(reviews);
    return (
        <section>
            {reviews.map((review) => {
                return <h2>It is working!</h2>;
            })}
        </section>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

data.js

```
const reviews = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'susan smith',
        job: 'web developer',
        image:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg',
        text: "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'anna johnson',
        job: 'web designer',
        image:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg',
        text: 'Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal.',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'peter jones',
        job: 'intern',
        image:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg',
        text: 'Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag.',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'bill anderson',
        job: 'the boss',
        image:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg',
        text: 'Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. ',
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const AppContext = React.createContext(
    /*here u should set default value as empty array or data object.*/
)
```

initial value of context is undefined so you are getting the error
and access like this

```
const reviews = useGlobalContext()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not destructure your context, you're simply assigning an array to it, so it's just

`const reviews = useGlobalContext()`

Also it's always good idea to assign some initial context values so you can debug things like that more precisely or further implement some logic for placeholders etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help.